# Laravel eloquent - One to many relationships (Trying to get property of non-object)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have "posts" table that has many-to-one relationship with "categories" table. The goal is to show all of posts and their categories.

Tables:
**Posts**: id, content, category_id, etc
**Categories**: id,name

Here's my code

Models:

```
class Posts extends Eloquent
{
    public static $table = 'posts';

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('Categories');
    }
}

class Categories extends Eloquent
{
    public static $table = 'categories';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->has_many('posts');
    }
}
```

My controller

```
public function get_posts()
{
    $posts = Posts::with('categories')->all();

    return View::make('admin.posts')
        ->with('title', 'Posts')
        ->with('posts', $posts);

}
```

My view

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ $post->categories->name }}</td>
            <td><small> {{$post->updated_at}} </small></td>
            <td>
                <button>
                    {{HTML::link_to_route('edit_post','Edit',array($post->id))}}
                </button>
                {{Form::open('admin/delete','Delete')}}
                {{Form::hidden('id', $post->id)}}
                <input type="submit" name="edit_post" value="Delete"/>
                {{Form::close()}}
            </td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

ERROR:

```
Error rendering view: [admin.posts]
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I am a newbie, please help me solve this issues

Answer (score 2):

{{ $post->categories->name }}  before test is categories exists

Example:

```
@if( ! empty($post->categories))
    <td>{{ $post->categories->name }}</td> 
@else

@end if
```

Aesis.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `::all()` instead of `::with(..)->all()`

Comment: I changed it to what you said, but still the same. Any other solution?

Comment: pass foreign key names to the relationships. and a recommendation: use singular names for db tables

Answer (score 0):

categories is an array as you are using a has_many relationship. There are many categories, hence an array is returned, so to access it you have to index it like an array

the correct solution would be

$post->categories[0]->name

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Laravel 4? First the syntax for declaring relationship is hasMany and belongsTo, in camel case. Check it out in [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

In view, check if categories are empty collection, ie., whether post has its category:

```
@if($post->categories->count())
    <td>{{ $post->categories->name }}</td>
    ...
@endif
```

By the way, I would use singular form as model class name, like Post and Category instead of plural forms. And in Post class I would define inverse one-to-many relationship with singular form, to show there's only one entry in category table for this given Post.

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
```